# in R how to convert a date in character format to numeric and then easily calculate the difference between two dates

Tags: r, string, date

So I want to convert "October 2010" and "November 2010" to a numeric format and hence if I take the difference of these two I get result: 1.

I tried to use as.date function but it seems that it only works for full format: month-day-year.

Comment: I tried use the command: as.Date(as.yearmon(x)) but it gives me the date by default, how can I keep only the month and the year?

Answer (score 0):

You can try formatting your raw date strings, and treating each one as being on the first day of that month.

```
dates <- c("October 2010", "November 2010")
# extract the first three letters for the month, and the last 4 digits for the year
dates.new <- paste0(substr(dates, 1, 3), "-01-", substr(dates, nchar(dates)-3, nchar(dates)))
> dates.new
[1] "Oct-01-2010" "Nov-01-2010"

# convert to POSIXct
dates.posix <- as.POSIXct(dates.new, format="%B-%d-%y")

diff <- dates.posix[2] - dates.posix[1]
> diff
Time difference of 31 days
```

Answer (score 0):

In your question you want to calculate the difference in number of months and not in number of days. You could map your `month-year` character vector to a numeric number of months, starting at month 1 with the first month in your dataset and ending with month n with the last month in your dataset. Then it would be straightforward to calculate a difference in number of months.

Alternatively - to be able to manipulate date-time objects - you will have to create full dates, by introducing a 01 in front of all dates for example "01 November 2010" and then calculating the difference between dates. This the main part of the answer below.

## Manipulating date-time objects

The lubridate package can calculate the difference between two dates. It deals with non trivial issues such as February 29th. If it's not installed on your system:

```
install.packages("lubridate")
```

Then

```
library(lubridate)
ymd("20160301")-ymd("20160228")
# Time difference of 2 days
ymd("20150301")-ymd("20150228")
# Time difference of 1 days
```

To read full month names look at formatting details in [help(parse_date_time)](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/lubridate/docs/parse_date_time)

```
d <- parse_date_time("November 01 2010", "Bdy") - parse_date_time("October 01 2010", "Bdy")
d
# Time difference of 31 days
```

d is a `difftime` object, (based on [converting a difftime to integer](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-May/162719.html)) you can convert it to a numeric number of days and weeks (but not to a number of months):

```
class(d)
# [1] "difftime"
as.numeric(d, units="days")
# [1] 31
as.numeric(d, units="weeks")
# [1] 4.428571
```